# Track total execution time of multi-thread java program

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java program that checks if numbers are prime. I tried to make it parallel by checking different numbers using separate threads.

Here is my sequential program, primeSeq.java:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.lang.Object;

class primeSeq {

    static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        // Check base cases:
        // n < 2, n is 2 or 3, n is divisible by 2 or 3
        if(n < 2) return false;
        if(n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
        if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;

        // Check if divisible by all numbers 6k +-1 up to sqrt(n)
        long sqrtN = (long)Math.sqrt(n)+1;
        for(long i = 6L; i <= sqrtN; i += 6) {
            if(n%(i-1) == 0 || n%(i+1) == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
    {
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("No args provided.");
        }
        else
        {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            for(int i=0;i< args.length;i++)
            {
                long single_startTime = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime());
                boolean isPrime = isPrime(Long.parseLong(args[i]));
                long single_endTime = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime());
                System.out.println(args[i] + ": " + isPrime + "\tStart time: " + single_startTime + "\tEnd time: " + single_endTime + "\tElapsed time: " + (single_endTime - single_startTime));

            }

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Total time: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt at parallelizing it, primePar.java:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.lang.Object;

class MyThread extends Thread
{
    boolean isPrime(long n) {
        // Check base cases:
        // n < 2, n is 2 or 3, n is divisible by 2 or 3
        if(n < 2) return false;
        if(n == 2 || n == 3) return true;
        if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0) return false;

        // Check if divisible by all numbers 6k +-1 up to sqrt(n)
        long sqrtN = (long)Math.sqrt(n)+1;
        for(long i = 6L; i <= sqrtN; i += 6) {
            if(n%(i-1) == 0 || n%(i+1) == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    String threadName;
    public MyThread(String threadName)
    {
        super(threadName);
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        long startTime = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime());
        boolean isPrime = isPrime(Long.parseLong(threadName));
        long endTime = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime());
        System.out.println(threadName + ": " + isPrime + "\tStart time: " + startTime + "\tEnd time: " + endTime + "\tElapsed time: " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
}

class primePar {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
    {
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("No args provided.");
        }
        else
        {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            for(int i=0;i< args.length;i++)
            {

                Thread newThread = new MyThread(args[i]);
                newThread.start();
            }

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Total time: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of these:

PrimeSeq:

```
$ java primeSeq 1000000000000037 1000000000000091 1000000000000159 1000000000000187
1000000000000037: true  Start time: 143773080   End time: 143773182 Elapsed time: 102
1000000000000091: true  Start time: 143773183   End time: 143773284 Elapsed time: 101
1000000000000159: true  Start time: 143773284   End time: 143773400 Elapsed time: 116
1000000000000187: true  Start time: 143773400   End time: 143773510 Elapsed time: 110
Total time: 430 milliseconds
```

PrimePar:

```
$ java primePar 1000000000000037 1000000000000091 1000000000000159 1000000000000187
Total time: 0 milliseconds
1000000000000091: true  Start time: 144449191   End time: 144449354 Elapsed time: 163
1000000000000159: true  Start time: 144449191   End time: 144449355 Elapsed time: 164
1000000000000187: true  Start time: 144449191   End time: 144449357 Elapsed time: 166
1000000000000037: true  Start time: 144449191   End time: 144449370 Elapsed time: 179
```

It seems that my parallel program is performing correctly since all the threads start at the same time. However, the total execution time is not what I wanted (it says 0 milliseconds). How can I change it so that it tracks the total execution time it takes for all the threads to finish (For the above output, it would be 179 milliseconds)?

Comment: Do you mean by *total execution time* all the execution times of the threads combined or the execution time of the overall program?

Comment: The overall program. All the threads should start at the same time, so whenever the thread that takes the longest finishes, that will be the end time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the execution time of the overall program, your main thread has to wait for the other threads to finish before calculating that. It is `0 milliseconds` because after the threads are created and started the main thread instantly goes to the final print while your threads are still running in the background.

In this case you need to collect the threads you have and then call `join()` on them. This method tells the thread from where the call happens - in this case the main thread - to wait for the thread, that you called the method on, to terminate before continuing. By doing this you will be sure that all the threads finished calculation before the main thread continues to the calculation of the overall execution time.

Something like this should work:

```java
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i< args.length;i++)
{

    Thread newThread = new MyThread(args[i]);
    newThread.start();
    threads.add(newThread);
}

threads.forEach(t -> {
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});

long endTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Total time: " + TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
```

Have a look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/joining-threads-in-java/) for more information.